# How to pass Google credentials for Vision Api in Node.js?

Tags: java, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-vision

I'm trying to pass **Google credentials** (without service account json files) to allow my **[Google Cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)** to make requests to the Google **[Cloud Vision Api](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries)**.

One week ago I created an Java spring app engine project in the flexible container and here I was able to let my code access the Cloud Vision Api and the Cloud firestore without providing service account json files, because they run on the same project on Google cloud.

Now I'm trying to achieve the same in a **Node.js** project, because I'm splitting up the Java code into multiple cloud functions.

I already created a working version in Java Spring by using the following code. I have also managed to make a connection with Cloud firestore by providing a service account json file, but again not without that.

## Version 1 - with service account file - Java

```
Credentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("path-to-json-file"));
```

## Version 2 - without service account - Java

***This version I need in my Node.js project***

```
   ImageAnnotatorSettings imageAnnotatorSettings =
   ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()               
   .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                        .build();
```

I just want the Google cloud functions that run on the same project to be 
automatically authenticated for the Cloud Vision API.